# Call a Jsp page in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I want to call a jsp page with in the javascript function without using this code

```
<form method="post" action="createxml.jsp">
```

I use the call like this but it is not working.

```
function questype()
{
createxml.jsp
}
```

Help me to call this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using any framework?

If don't, the "Action" value it's the JSP url that returns the JSP.

Example:
in your xml file, you has got something like this:

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>createXml.jsp</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/createXml.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>createXml.jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/createXml.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Later, you need to do something like this:

```
function questype()
{

    $.each($('form[action='createXml.jsp']').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
        values[field.name] = field.value;
    });
    $("<DIV WHENEVER YOU WANT TO PUT THE JSP RESULT>").load("createxml.jsp", values);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery:

```
function questype()
{
    var postVars = {};
    $.post("createxml.jsp", postVars, function(data){
         /** DO SOMETHING WITH RETURN INFO **/
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well either you need to create an ajax query, an anchor tag or some sort of form.